# MYSQL query to return rows that are NOT in a set

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Contact (id,name)
Link (id, contact_id, source_id)

I have the following query which works that returns the contacts with the source_id of 8 in the Link table.

```
SELECT name FROM `Contact` LEFT JOIN Link ON Link.contact_id = Contact.id WHERE Link.source_id=8;
```

However I am a little stumped on how to return a list of all the contacts which are NOT associated with source_id of 8. A simple != will not work as contacts without any links are not returned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT c.name 
     FROM CONTACT c
LEFT JOIN LINK l ON l.contact_id = c.id
                AND l.source_id = 8
    WHERE l.contact_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Nice one, thank you so much. I will accept it in a few mins when I can!

Comment: @iglurat: NP.  You can also use either `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`, but on MySQL the LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is more efficient: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

Just say `WHERE Link.source_id != 8;`

Comment: Sorry for the insults but this is a typical numb nuts reply of "lets get as much rep as I can".

Comment: Sorry a bit harsh there, I guess some peoples questions are even simpler than mine!

Answer (score 0):

There's a straight-forwarrd way to do it just as you expressed it.

SELECT name
FROM ....
WHERE Link.source_id != 8;

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `where` condition from:

```
Link.source_id = 8;
```

to

```
Link.source_id != 8;
```

You can also use `<>` in place of `!=`

Both are the [not equal operator in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt this work?

```
WHERE Link.source_id <> 8 OR Link.source_id IS NULL
```